# NoClassDefFoundError with ant

Tags: java, exception, ant, restlet, build.xml

I get the following exception when trying to ren serverresource class from ant. It is working with eclipse. Exception logs:. Classpath seems to be set, but restlet serverresource class is not found... Any help would be appreciated.

```
    run:
     [echo] Running Web Service
     [java] When using 'jar' attribute classpath-settings are ignored. See the manual for more information.
fileset: Setup scanner in dir C:\Users\Olga\workspace\people\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib with patternSet{ includes: [*.jar] excludes: [] }
     [java] Executing 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\java.exe' with arguments:
     [java] '-classpath'
     [java] 'C:\Users\Olga\workspace\people\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\axis.jar;C:\Users\Olga\workspace\people\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\commons-discovery-0
2.jar;C:\Users\Olga\workspace\people\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\commons-logging.jar;C:\Users\Olga\workspace\people\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\gson-2.1-source
.jar;C:\Users\Olga\workspace\people\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\gson-2.1.jar;C:\Users\Olga\workspace\people\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\javax.ws.rs.jar;C:\User
\Olga\workspace\people\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\jaxrpc.jar;C:\Users\Olga\workspace\people\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.jar;C:\Users\Olg
\workspace\people\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.restlet.jar;C:\Users\Olga\workspace\people\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\saaj.jar;C:\Users\Olga\workspace\peopl
\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\wsdl4j.jar;C:\Users\Olga\workspace\people\build'
     [java] '-jar'
     [java] 'C:\Users\Olga\workspace\people\build\People.jar'
     [java]
     [java] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
     [java] not part of the command.
Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\java.exe' with arguments:
'-classpath'
'C:\Users\Olga\workspace\people\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\axis.jar;C:\Users\Olga\workspace\people\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\commons-discovery-0.2.jar;C:\Us
rs\Olga\workspace\people\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\commons-logging.jar;C:\Users\Olga\workspace\people\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\gson-2.1-sources.jar;C:\Use
s\Olga\workspace\people\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\gson-2.1.jar;C:\Users\Olga\workspace\people\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\javax.ws.rs.jar;C:\Users\Olga\works
ace\people\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\jaxrpc.jar;C:\Users\Olga\workspace\people\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.jar;C:\Users\Olga\workspace\
eople\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\org.restlet.jar;C:\Users\Olga\workspace\people\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\saaj.jar;C:\Users\Olga\workspace\people\WebContent
WEB-INF\lib\wsdl4j.jar;C:\Users\Olga\workspace\people\build'
'-jar'
'C:\Users\Olga\workspace\people\build\People.jar'

The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
not part of the command.
     [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/restlet/resource/ServerResource
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
     [java]     at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
     [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
     [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
     [java]     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:476)
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.restlet.resource.ServerResource
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
     [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
     [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
     [java]     ... 13 more
     [java] Exception in thread "main"
     [java] Java Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in the message:

> When using 'jar' attribute classpath-settings are ignored.

You'll either need to use the classpath attribute within the jar file manifest, or include the jar file as part of the classpath and just specify the class name to execute.